# Couldn't load GLMapCore: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, arcgis-android

Im getting this Error when loading an ESRI map inside the Android Environment. This didn't happen with ESRI's .1 Alpha SDK, but it does happen with their 1.0.0 SDK.

I know it has something to do with the OpenGL lib, but can't seem to find a solution. I am running the Motorola Xoom Tablet with the latest Android environment.

Also Its using Fragments, so that might have something to do with it.

Here is my stack dump.

> 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.map.EsriMapWidget}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.esri.android.map.MapView 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1818) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.esri.android.map.MapView 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:671) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at .map.EsriMapFragment.onCreateView(EsriMapFragment.java:21) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:714) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:912) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:990) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:257) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:660) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:245) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at .EsriMapWidget.onCreate(EsriMapWidget.java:155) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): ... 11 more 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:416) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): ... 31 more 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at com.esri.android.map.MapView.a(Unknown Source) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at com.esri.android.map.MapView.(Unknown Source) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): ... 34 more 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at com.esri.android.map.MapSurface.(Unknown Source) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): ... 36 more 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load GLMapCore: findLibrary returned null 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:425) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): at com.esri.android.map.Layer.(Unknown Source) 01-24 14:20:31.290: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4370): ... 37 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for me was to open a sample ArcGIS app (in Eclipse, File > New > Other > ArcGIS for Android > ArcGIS Samples for Android) and copy the lib folder to my project.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS needs a self runtime Environment so you must add a runtime library to your project.

The *.so file path is /projectName/libs/armeabi-v7a/libruntimecore_java.so.

You are best to set the  ArcGIS plugin to your Eclipse so it can do this instead of you.